# Скрывать блоки по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть секция с проектами и кнопками, как сделать чтоб по нажатию определенной кнопки к ней дбавлялся класс .active и скрывались все блоки кроме блоков с определенным id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется фильтрация элементов

> смотреть на полном экране

```js
var fActive = '';

function filterColor(color) {
  if (fActive != color) {
    $('div').filter('.' + color).slideDown();
    $('div').filter(':not(.' + color + ')').slideUp();
    fActive = color;
  }
}

$('.f-red').click(function() {
  filterColor('red');
});
$('.f-blue').click(function() {
  filterColor('blue');
});
$('.f-green').click(function() {
  filterColor('green');
});

$('.f-all').click(function() {
  $('div').slideDown();
  fActive = 'all';
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0.25em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.f-red {
  background: #ff4136;
}

.f-red:hover {
  background: #e90d00;
}

.f-green {
  background: #2ecc40;
}

.f-green:hover {
  background: #208e2c;
}

.f-blue {
  background: #0074d9;
}

.f-blue:hover {
  background: #004b8c;
}

.f-all {
  background: #333;
}

.f-all:hover {
  background: #0d0d0d;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.red {
  background: #ff4136;
}

.green {
  background: #2ecc40;
}

.blue {
  background: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Фильтрация элементов с помощью jQuery</h2>

<p>
  <button class="f-red">Фильтр красных элементов</button>
  <button class="f-blue">Фильтр синих элементов</button>
  <button class="f-green">Фильтр зеленых элементов</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class="f-all">Все элементы</button>
</p>

<div class="red">Первый</div>
<div class="red">Второй</div>
<div class="blue">Третий</div>
<div class="green">Четвертый</div>
<div class="red">Пятый</div>
<div class="blue">Шестой</div>
<div class="blue">Седьмой</div>
<div class="green">Восьмой</div>
```